# Events not firing when element does not exist initially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I am using jQuerys .on() to bind event handlers to a video element. And everything works great: http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/r0zt4qLg/3/

```
$('#testid').on('pause play ended', function (e) {
    $('body').append('<br>Event triggered: ' + e.type);
});
```

But if the video does not initially exist, the events are not firing: http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/r0zt4qLg/5/

Which makes sense because according to the jQuery documentation on .on() : http://api.jquery.com/on/
It states:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().

and it goes on to saying to use delegated events,

but as in my example(http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/r0zt4qLg/5/) the parent element will never fire those events, because they do not apply there.
Is there a way to make this work or is the only solution to attach the event handlers once the element exists?

Comment: The problem is that events from HTML5 media elements don't bubble.

Comment: I can't make it work with the solution of the "duplicate question" : http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/r0zt4qLg/8/

Answer (score 1):

you have delegate the events like this:

```
$(document).on('pause play ended','#testid', function (e) {
    $('body').append('<br>Event triggered: ' + e.type);
});
```

Comment: This will not fix the problem.

Comment: if you look at my second example, it is properly delegated, but like Pointy said that dose not fix the problem.